# ¿Cómo puedo calcular la media de tiempo en Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, mediaqueries

Cada vez que un usuario hace algo queda registrada la fecha.
Por ejemplo tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
|usuario|Timestamp |
|-------|----------|
|   1   |2021-03-04|
|   1   |2021-03-04|
|   1   |2021-03-06|
|   1   |2021-03-07|
|   2   |2021-03-02|
|   2   |2021-03-05|
|   2   |2021-03-07|
|   3   |2021-03-08|
|   3   |2021-03-03|
```

Y me gustaría saber el tiempo medio hasta que el usuario hace algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo así:

Primero (en la query interna) calculo la diferencia entre una fecha y la anterior en días (para cada usuario), luego hago el promedio por usuario.

Si la columna "Fecha" es de tipo date (castie la columna fecha a date para que funcione tambien en caso de que sea del tipo timestamp):

```
SELECT usuario, round(avg(dias_entre_actividad), 2) AS promedio_dias
FROM (

     SELECT
         usuario,
         fecha::date - lag(fecha::date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY usuario ORDER BY fecha ASC) AS dias_entre_actividad
     FROM t) AS aux

GROUP BY usuario
ORDER BY promedio_dias ASC;
```

Si la columna "Fecha" es de tipo timestamp, debes usar esta query:

```
SELECT usuario, ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM dias_entre_actividad) / 86400)::numeric, 2) AS promedio_dias
FROM (

SELECT
    usuario,
    fecha - lag(fecha, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY usuario ORDER BY fecha ASC) AS dias_entre_actividad
FROM t) AS aux

GROUP BY usuario
ORDER BY promedio_dias ASC;
```

La salida para tus datos de ejemplo sería:

| usuario | promedio_dias |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 2.50 |
| 3 | 5.00 |

Comment: Muchas Gracias! me sale un error ya que dias entre actividad lo toma como intervalo y la funcion round no permite este tipo. He probado a hacer un cast pero no funciona.alguna idea?

Comment: De nada! En Postgresql-13 lo estás probando? asi tagueaste la pregunta (pero también con Postgresql-9.3).

Comment: La columna Fecha es del tipo date? o es timestamp?

Comment: Aparentemente tu columna "Fecha" es de tipo timestamp (lo cual no coincide con el ejemplo que subiste). Edité la respuesta y agregué otra query para usar con tipo timestamp.

Comment: De nada! Si en el timestamp tenés datos de la hora, los minutos, etc los va a tener en cuenta. Quizas te conviene utilizar la primer query y castear la fecha (timestamp) a date.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! parece que ya funciona